# Object inside canvas move faster whenever i press button

Tags: javascript

So i have something similar to snake game ( with just head) but when ever i press button call function change direction ( left, right ....) it keep going faster.I think it because setimeout but
i dont know where to put cleartimeout can you guy help me ?

```
function automove() {    
     Snake[1] = snake[1] + y;
     Snake[0] = snake[0] + x;
    }
  function left() {
    x = -5; 
    y = 0;
    if( i = 1) {
        start();
     }};
  function start() {
       gamerun = true;
       drawotobody();
       nextmove();
     };
  function nextmove() {
      if(gamerun = true){
        setTimeout(()=>{
        contactborder();
        clearboard();
        drawotobody();
        automove();
        nextmove();
       }, 75);}
     };
```